# Random motion that doesn't stray too far from point of origin (BGE)?

Tags: game-engine, constraints, logic-bricks

Imagine you have a large room with 100 balloons that are floating in the middle of it. I'm working in BGE and need to figure out how to give each balloon random motion (up, down, left, right, forward back), but I need to keep the balloons from wandering off. They need to stay relatively put in their plane/position.

I've added a constraint to a balloon to keep it within -.1 and .1 in all directions. I've done the same with rotation.

When I add random movement in the game logic, however, it seems to just override my constraints I've set. :( Any ideas?

Comment: So I have been able to get the random movement I need for the most part. I was trying to use the transform as a way to constrain the random movement generated by the BGE logic blocks. Instead, I added random movement logic blocks along each axis and then I also added logic blocks set to Always that constrained the movement along each axis.

One thing that has been really annoying is that none of this appears to work along local axis, so I have to find the position of each object and modify its logic blocks accordingly. Also, I can't figure out rotation constraints :(

Comment: You should post your findings below as an aswer, complete with an explanation of how to achieve it, preferably with screenshots of the results